# Is it possible to explain why $\sum e^{2n}/6^{n-1}$ is divergent without using any tests?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm pretty sure $\sum e^{2n}/6^{n-1}$ can be expressed as a geometric series with some algebra. Let's say a geometric series is defined as one that looks like: $\sum ar^{n-1}$, where $a$ is unchanging and $r$ is the common ratio. Here's what I'm doing:

$e^{2n} = e^2 \cdot e^n = e^2 \cdot e(e^{n-1}) = e^3 \cdot e^{n-1}$

So now it's: $\sum ( e^3 \cdot e^{n-1} / 6^{n-1})$, which is a geometric series with $a=e^3$ and $r=e/6$.

The sum of a geometric ratio exists so long as $|r|<0$, which $e/6$ satisfies, so I'm not understanding why the series is divergent (I understand that applying the ratio test tells you that the series diverges, but I'm wondering why my solution is wrong).

Comment: $e^{2n}\ne e^2e^n$? It is only correct to say that $e^{2n}=(e^n)^2=(e^2)^n$

Comment: @PeterForeman wow I am silly, thank you!

Comment: Btw, the ratio tests computes precisely $r$ and that's the reason why it works

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for the response, that's really interesting! I don't quite understand though: the ratio tests can be used on series that aren't geometric. Do all series, not just geometric ones, have a common ratio $r$ or equivalent idea? If not, what exactly is the ratio test computing? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

because $$r=\frac{e^2}{6}>1$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Would you mind telling me how you got $r=e^2/6$? I can't seem to figure the algebra out.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: sorry I think you missed the last part of my response, could you possible tell me how you got $r=e^2/6$? Sorry for being stupid, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: $$\sum \frac{e^{2n}}{6^{n-1}}=6\sum \frac{(e^2)^n}{6^{n}}=6\sum (\frac{e^2}{6})^n$$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{2n}=e^n\cdot e^n$, not $e^2\cdot e^n$.

Comment: That was careless of me, thank you!